# Definite integral of $\sin(x)/x$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, estimation

I'm trying to evaluate absolute value of:

$$\left | \int_{a}^{b} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx \right | \leq\frac{2}{a}, \ \text{where}\ 0<a<b$$

I tried taylor series, mean value theorems, and tried to divide interval on some like $\left[\pi k, \pi(k+1) \right]$ or $\left[2\pi k, 2\pi(k+1) \right]$, but it didn't help

Comment: You need to find the value of that integral or just bound it by $2/a$?

Comment: @Azif00, just bound it by $ 2/a $, that's all

Comment: Consider the integral $I(a)=\int e^{-ax}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx$, and $I'(a)=-\int e^{-ax}\sin x dx$..proceed from there..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use
$$ \int\frac{\sin x}xdx=-\int\frac1xd\cos x=-\frac{\cos x}{x}-\int\frac{\cos x}{x^2}dx.$$
one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\bigg|\int_a^b\frac{\sin x}xdx\bigg|\\
&=&\bigg|-\frac{\cos x}{x}\bigg|_a^b-\int_a^b\frac{\cos x}{x^2}dx\bigg|\\
&\le&\bigg|\frac{\cos a}{a}-\frac{\cos b}{b}\bigg|+\int_a^b\frac1{x^2}dx\\
&\le&\frac{1}{a}+\frac1b+\frac1a-\frac1b\\
&=&\frac{2}{a}.
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 2):

Integrate by parts and let $u=\frac{1}{x}$ and $dv=\sin(x)\,dx$ to get

$$\int_{a}^{b} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \,dx=\frac{\cos(a)}{a}-\frac{\cos(b)}{b}-\int_a^b \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2}\,dx.$$

Then, by the triangle inequality,

\begin{align}\left|\int_{a}^{b} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \,dx\right|&=
\left|\frac{\cos(a)}{a}-\frac{\cos(b)}{b}-\int_a^b \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2}\,dx\right|\\&\le
\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\int_a^b \left|\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2}\right|\,dx\\&\le
\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\int_a^b \frac{1}{x^2}\,dx\\&=
\frac{2}{a}.
\end{align}